# Swift TableViewDataSource Separate Other Class

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have two examples

First

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.dataSource = TableViewDataSource();
}
```

Second

```
var dataSource:TableViewDataSource!;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    dataSource = TableViewDataSource();
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

First example does not work but second works. Are these not the same? And What is the difference between two examples?

Comment: Unrelated but in Swift you do not need semicolons (`;`) at the end of lines.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah i know but this is habit :D

Comment: Well break the habit. Do you press your left foot the floor in your automatic transmission car each time it shifts gears?

Answer (score 1):

first one not works because you have to set a strong reference to it

```
tableView.dataSource = TableViewDataSource();
```

while the other have it here

```
var dataSource:TableViewDataSource!;
```

//

If you looked to dataSource delegate implementation file , it's declared like this

```
weak open var dataSource:UITableViewDataSource?
```

look carfeully to **weak** so it doesn't retain vars assigned to it that's why the other class instance must be strongly referenced

[image]

Comment: Why i need strong reference?  As a result 2 example return same thing yes?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView dataSource` is a weak property. Your first example doesn't work because there is no strong reference to the `TableViewDataSource` instance that you create. By the time the end of `viewDidLoad` is reached, the instance is deallocated and `dataSource` is reset back to `nil`.

Your second example works because your `dataSource` property of your class maintains a strong reference to the `TableViewDataSource` instance. As long as your view controller exists, the `TableViewDataSource` will exist and the table view's data source will work.

Comment: But as a result this is same thing yeah? 
TableViewDataSource() return object and assign tableview.dataSource

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your two examples are not the same and I explained why they are different.